# send array from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hello i need help i am trying to pass three different variables from the controller of a codeigniter to model so i created an array and pass it then i exploded and i am getting the error **explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

The controller

```
 $data = array(
                'district_id' => $this->input->post('district') ,
                'limit' => $limit,
                'offset' => $offset,

            );


   $data['tubadili'] = $this->wapi_db->search_bar($data);
```

The Model function

```
public function search_bar($data){

    $dataArray = explode(',' , $data);

    $district_id = $dataArray[0];

    $limit = $dataArray[1];

    $offset = $dataArray[2];

    $this->db->select('entertainment.Name,entertainment.ID,entertainment.Category,entertainment.Location,entertainment.Description,
                       image.ImagePath,image.Enter_ID,entertainment.DistrictID');

    $this->db->from('entertainment');

    $this->db->join('image', 'image.Enter_ID=entertainment.ID');

     $this->db->where('entertainment.Category',"Bar");

     $this->db->where('entertainment.DistrictID', $district_id);


    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();








}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$dataArray = explode(',' , $data);
$district_id = $dataArray[0];
$limit = $dataArray[1];
$offset = $dataArray[2];
```

To:

```
extract($data);
```

Basically what this does is take the associative array you have in `$data` and extracts them into their own variables, which is logically equal to:

```
$district_id = $data['district_id'];
$limit = $data['limit'];
$offset = $data['offset'];
```

Your issue is that you were trying to explode `$data` which will not work, explode works on strings and not arrays.

Comment: Hello Thank you Very Much It is working Perfectly Gracies @Aziz